# jmeter -distributed testing - log file is incomplete

Tags: jmeter, distributed-testing

I have setup jmeter in distributed testing with 1 master and 2 slaves on AWS and things seem to be running with following command:

./jmeter.sh -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1 -n -t Ping.jmx -R 127.0.0.1:24001,127.0.0.1:24002 -l out.csv

Ping.jmx is configured with 20 threads for a ramp up of 20 secs.
The issue is out.csv does not have all the data from remote servers for all requests made. I expect 40 requests made from 2 remote servers. I can see the jmeter-server.log on remote servers and see that all 20 threads are being executed.
The size of the log file has only 4 requests all the time irrespective of the number of threads.
Any pointers?

The out.csv looks like this:
[root@ip-10-0-2-49 bin]# vi out.csv
timeStamp;elapsed;label;responseCode;threadName;success;bytes;sentBytes;grpThreads;allThreads;Latency;SampleCount;ErrorCount;Hostname;IdleTime;Connect

21:03:49;97;HTTP Request;;AXN API Thread Group 1-1;true;545;184;0;0;97;1;0;ip-10-0-2-224;0;85

21:03:47;107;HTTP Request;;AXN API Thread Group 1-1;true;564;184;0;0;107;1;0;ip-10-0-2-197;0;99

21:03:53;254;HTTP Request;;AXN API Thread Group 1-2;true;2218;736;0;0;253;4;0;ip-10-0-2-224;0;206

21:03:51;255;HTTP Request;;AXN API Thread Group 1-2;true;2199;736;0;0;255;4;0;ip-10-0-2-197;0;209

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce you issue so my expectation is that your configuration is not very correct, you need to provide more details regarding it.

[image: JMeter same host distributed execution]

Few recommendations:

1. Running JMeter in distributed mode on a single machine doesn't make any sense, it only causes overhead required to keep master and each other JMeter instance running. In order to get the maximum performance from a single JMeter you need to follow recommendations from [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) article. Also it worth seeing [JMeter Distributed Testing Step-by-step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.pdf) guide just in case you haven't got a chance to read it yet.
2. There is [JMeter EC2 script](https://github.com/oliverlloyd/jmeter-ec2) which you can utilize or use as a basic for your research, theoretically it should simplify deploying and configuring JMeter on Amazon.
3. Don't run software as root unless you absolutely require it, it is kind of dangerous.

Comment: thanks for the links. the issue stemmed from the configuration of "mode" element to be Statistical but when i changed to standard, i started receiving all the results. What is the recommended setting for "mode" to get the best response times? Here is how i have it now remote_hosts=127.0.0.1:24001,127.0.0.1:24002
client.rmi.localport=25000
mode=standard

Comment: I believe default setting is [StrippedBatch](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html#sendermode), it removes response data from successful samplers and sends them to the master in batches.